# How to rotate video on rotate of device in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, android-videoview

I am working on a project where I am showing a live streaming video in android. I am showing the video in video view. I want to provide facility of landscape and portrait video view to the user. If I rotate the device the video should be bigger in width. But currently If I do so it takes lots of time to reload the video from the web. Is it possible that video should work fine for this. I mean it should play normally and just the width increase. 
I am able to achieve the same in iOS.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        questionVideo.setDimensions(displayHeight, displayWidth);
        questionVideo.getHolder().setFixedSize(displayHeight, displayWidth);

    } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        questionVideo.setDimensions(displayWidth, smallHeight);
        questionVideo.getHolder().setFixedSize(displayWidth, smallHeight);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

In your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. This way your Activity wont be restarted automatically. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) for more information..